# Making variables not equal to each other

Tags: python, variables

I'm currently making a code whose function is to make a 2D array filled with a function which calculates multiples of a value `x` in `range (1,10)`.

```
def find_multiples (twolist, count) : 

    n = random.randrange(1,10)

    for i in range(count) :
        for j in range(count) :
            x = random.randrange(0,101,n)
            twolist[i][j] = x
```

The next part is inputting randomly a value "y" which is different from x in a random place within the array.

```
y = random.randrange(0,101)
a = random.randrange(count)
b = random.randrange(count)
twolist[a][b] = y
return twolist, y
```

My question is, how do I make y a different value from x? I was thinking maybe I have to make a separate defined function which acts to check if y is not a multiple of n but I'm not quite sure how to word it.

```
def check_diffmult (numx , numy) :

    for i in range(1,numx) :
        if numy = random.randrange(0,101,i) :
```

This was my attempt so far, but I know it's off.

Edit : Thanks for the replies so far! So far, there isn't much else to the code except for this. The overall goal is for there to be a random integer y that is is a different pattern from the multiples of n which go through the function. Not sure if that's enough to clear things up! Also, I read a reply further down that y is as easy as x + 1, but I'm hesitant in changing a value of y by simply adding or subtracting since y could then accidentally become one of the multiples of the randomly chosen value of "n".

Edit 2 :

```
def check_diffmult (numx , numy) :
check_list = []
check_list.append(numx)
if numy == check_list :
    return 0
return 1
```

def find_multiples (twolist, count) :

```
n = random.randrange(1,10)
for i in range(count) :
    for j in range(count) :
        x = random.randrange(0,101,n)
        twolist[i][j] = x

while True :

    y = random.randrange(0,101)
    check = check_list(x,y)
    if check == 1 :
        a = random.randrange(count)
        b = random.randrange(count)

        twolist[a][b] = y
        break

return twolist, y
```

Changed code to this to make y != x . Could this be a viable code?

Comment: Your code is broken and incomplete. Please edit it to make it more readable.

Comment: @MeetTitan +1 could make the y go out of range

Comment: Could could place the numbers in a set, which does not have duplicates, and loop until you have the correct `len()`.

Comment: @cdarke By the numbers, I'm assuming you're talking about the values that are generated as x?

Comment: Yes, but anything that you want to be unique.

Comment: @cdarke Thanks! I think I got it figured out.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like:

```
x, y = random.sample(range(0, 101, n), 2)
```

Quoting the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html#random.sample):

> #### `random.sample(population, k)`
>
> Return a *k* length list of **unique elements** chosen from the population sequence or set. Used for random sampling without replacement. [...]
>
> To choose a sample from a range of integers, use an `range()` object as an argument.

(If you're using Python 2, you might want to use [`xrange()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) instead.)